# In Android, how do I position an image on top of another to look like a badge?

Tags: android-layout, android

Please see below:

[image: iPhone badges]

I tried using Absolute layout, but that's deprecated.   I appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Never, *ever*, ***ever*** use `AbsoluteLayout`. Ever.

Comment: @AlexLockwood : So what you're trying to say is that people shouldn't use `AbsoluteLayout`? Just thought I'd check. ;D

Comment: @Squonk, There is no such thing as "too much emphasis" when it comes to these things... especially on StackOverflow :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) is a great option.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/iconImage" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon"
    android:src="@drawable/badge" />
```

If you actually want a badge with a dynamic number/text, then you can make the second `ImageView` a `TextView` (or a `ViewGroup` such as `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`) and give it a background drawable and set the text to what you want.

Comment: @Sam Dozor How do i get the badge imageview to show up on outer part of the first ImageView (it is currently showing inside of imageview icon).

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the [ViewBadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger) project on github(but keep in mind that you shouldn't try to copy other platforms UI elements in android apps).

Comment: I normally hate +1, but +1.  Been there, done it, a world of pain - never again.