# Android List view with avatar

Tags: android, listview

I have a created a listview with 1 imageView, and 2 textViews. How do I add a smaller image on top of the avatar image as shown in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly it sounds like you want to add a badge to your image.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090015/in-android-how-do-i-position-an-image-on-top-of-another-to-look-like-a-badge) stackoverflow question for a good answer.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for.